# How to mount and use iso file in windows repair mode

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, cmd.exe, iso-image

I'm stuck in windows repair mode of windows 10. Not even able to reset windows. So I have to install a fresh windows but my windows iso file stored in f:/windows and I have a usb drive that I am using as bootable. But in my usb drive Linux system is stored. How can I format the usb driver than mount and copy iso file to usb in repair mode using cmd. (I can still use cmd in repair mode)

Comment: Are you asking how to format your flash drive and make it contain the contents of the ISO?

Comment: If repair mode won't work, either Windows is very damaged, or you may have a bad disk. Test your disk and then use the ISO file to install Windows fresh. I trust you have good backups.

Comment: You have a 2nd Windows computer you can use to create the Windows USB from there? If yes the best would be to create the USB using the media creation tool from https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10

Comment: To clear and change the USB partitioning, use `diskpart.exe`. But just copying the ISO to the USB stick will not solve your problem. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1781472/windows-10-installation-keeps-restarting-from-the-beginning-after-successful-ins/1781662#1781662) to get an idea. — Do you use UEFI or Legacy BIOS?

Comment: As you can boot Linux from USB, and if you can connect another USB, create Windows boot on the second USB. If you can't manage to access the ISO, download it to the Linux USB. See [this article](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-create-windows-bootable-usb-linux/).