# Install Windows 11,10 UEFI Setting

Tags: linux, uefi, window, acer

I have been trying to install windows 11/10 in my Laptop Acer nitro 5, Previously it had windows installed but wipe out and install ubuntu on it and now I want to install windows 10/11 againts it always showing me the black screen mention EFI folder with something that could be the bootloader, I don't know if there any configuration setting that I can do in order to have installed windows correctly so I'm open to receive any kind of help.

extra information:

when I tried the Window ISO 10/11 and pass the error, the disk selection is not showing any disk, but normally I can boot ubuntu.

Comment: UEFI is effectively BIOS for the system. It is most definitely not a setting. You probably need to format and start fresh.

Comment: I want to format it but it seems I can't see any disk in the computer(it has 2 disk, one ssd and one not ssd.), I disabled secured boot.

Comment: Try using the Windows 10 or 11 ISO.  Make a bootable USB (Rufus). Start with this and see if you can format and install Windows. If not, there may be a hardware issue.

Comment: I will try, but how can it be a hardware issue because Im writting this post in the machine?

Comment: Try (it may not be a hardware issue, unless there is a disk issue)

Comment: A short hint: *To get qualified answers you should provide qualified details in your question.*

Comment: `black screen mentioning EFI folder` - Obvioulsy you end up in the UEFI Command Shell. Before trying various things, check your Windows Setup on the USB. How did you create it? — There is online at Microsoft a media creation tool that will download and apply the Windows installer image to the USB. If you already have a Windows ISO then use `Rufus`  to create the media. For *important* details and guidance see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1781662/1787250).

Answer (score -2):

I found, if you remove drivers by "Windows install tool", it doesn't wipe all information on driver. When I test for write(just it) my driver by AIDA64, it clear all info. Then I did installation correctly.

Comment: What is the "Windows Install Tool"? This is a fresh OS install, not a reinstall or refresh, so there were not pre-existing drivers.

Comment: I meant "Windows setup". When you remove all information to install new OS. I had same problem. That was solved when I wipe driver by separated application, and than I could install new OS.